# Attach event to iframe element in parent code

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-events

In my application, I have an iframe and I would like to give it access to some functionality which changes the state of the application outside the iframe.  This functionality must be triggered by a `keydown` event either inside or outside the iframe.

In the iframe, I have the following code:

```
window.init = function (api) {
    api.bind(document);
};
```

And the outer application does something like:

```
iframe.contentWindow.init({
    bind: function (element) {
        $(element).bind('keydown', function () {
            debugger;
        });
    }
});
```

With this, `init` is called properly, but the `keydown` event handler is never called.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that some part of the iframe has already attached a `keydown` handler which stops propagation of the event, preventing the event from reaching the document and preventing the handler from being called.  Nothing was wrong with the actual binding.

Answer (score 4):

If you try to bind event in this way:

```
    $(element).bind('keydown', function () {
        alert("hello");
    });
```

jquery will try to traverse your element in parent `window`, but if you do the following your problem would be solved:

```
    $(iframe.contentWindow.document.body).find(element).bind('keydown', function () {
        alert("hello");
    });
```

Comment: Just to add: `$(iframe.contentWindow.document.body)` can be replaced by `$(iframe).contents()`.